# Topic of the week: It's Apps Week! Ask and win prizes~ Now closed

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Last month, we kicked off a **"Topic of the Week"** series, and this week is **applications week**!

How it works: Each person who asks a question about/relating to any Android app will be entered into a drawing to win a grand prize.

The more questions you ask, the greater your chance of winning.

Examples may include (but are not at all limited to these):

- functioning of a particular app
- using an existing app as a solution to a problem
- performance or compatibility concerns with certain apps

How to enter: Ask a question about any Android app and tag it [applications](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) (along with any other appropriate tag). Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win Android accessories (your choice up to $100). Eligible questions should have a net positive score (no overwhelming downvotes).

Dates: Apps week begins now and will end Wednesday January 18.

Update: Thank you for participating! Apps week is now over.

*Congratulations to Mr. Buster for winning this week!*